# Delete rows where any column contains number

Tags: r

This is almost certainly a duplicate question, but I can't find an an answer anywhere on SO. Most of the other similar questions relate to subsetting from one column, rather than an entire dataframe.

I have a dataframe:

```
test = data.frame(
'A' = c(.31562, .48845, .27828, -999),
'B' = c(.5674, 5.7892, .4687, .1345),
'C' = c(-999, .3145, .0641, -999))
```

I want to drop rows where *any* column contains -999, so that my dataframe will look like this:

```
           A      B         C
2    0.48845 5.7892    0.3145
3    0.27828 0.4687    0.0641
```

I am sure there is an easy way to do this with the subset() function, or apply(), but I just can't figure it out.

I tried this:

```
test[apply(test, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {-999 != x}), ]
```

But it returns:

```
              A      B         C
1       0.31562 0.5674 -999.0000
2       0.48845 5.7892    0.3145
4    -999.00000 0.1345 -999.0000
NA           NA     NA        NA
NA.1         NA     NA        NA
NA.2         NA     NA        NA
NA.3         NA     NA        NA
NA.4         NA     NA        NA
NA.5         NA     NA        NA
```

Comment: `test[!apply(test, 1, function(r) any(r == -999)),]`

Comment: you could deal with this at an earlier stage: when reading in set `na.strings="-999"` . Then the usual tools for removing rows with missing data can be used.

Comment: With `rowSums`, you could do `test[rowSums(test == -999) == 0,]`, but using `na.strings` in the read argument is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Use `arr.ind` with `which` to obtain the rows where `-999` is present (`which(test == -999, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]`)and remove those rows.

```
test[-unique(which(test == -999, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]),]
#        A      B      C
#2 0.48845 5.7892 0.3145
#3 0.27828 0.4687 0.0641
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce`

```
test[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(test, `==`, -999)),]
#        A      B      C
#2 0.48845 5.7892 0.3145
#3 0.27828 0.4687 0.0641
```