# Delete All Rows With Any of N Variables

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-management

[Delete rows where any column contains number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635575/delete-rows-where-any-column-contains-number)

[Finding rows containing a value (or values) in any column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233561/finding-rows-containing-a-value-or-values-in-any-column)

Finding rows containing a value (or values) in any column

Extending on the question from the post above.

Suppose I have a dataset called m5:

```
set.seed(1234)
m3 <- matrix(12:1,nrow=6,ncol=4)
m4<-as.data.frame(m3)
m5 <- m4[sample(nrow(m4)),]
```

How do I select only rows where any column contains the value 12 or 9 or 7.

The end output should be rows 1, 2, and 6.

Also would be helpful if the proposed answer works for strings as well.

Comment: Note that your dataframe `m6` is a random sample and you haven't given any `set.seed()` starting value. So everybody who tries your sample will get different results.

Comment: @eastclintw00d Sorry I did but I misformatted the post, here is the seed I used so should be good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try:

```
m5[apply(m5, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c(12, 9, 7))), ]
```

Giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
4  9  3  9  3
1 12  6 12  6
6  7  1  7  1
```

There's also a `dplyr` possibility, but that may be an overkill:

```
dplyr::filter_all(m5, any_vars(. %in% c(12, 9, 7)))
```